# How to quiet the output of command in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, systemctl

I have written the following command in my bash script:
`service service1 status | grep -q "good"`

Here, I am trying to `quiet` the output of command `service service1 status`

Please suggest how that can be done?

I have tried `service service1 status | grep -q "good" > /dev/null` but it is still giving output of command if `service service1 status` fails

Comment: Hm, If you want to mute the output what is this `grep` for then? If you mute, there's nothing to grep?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski:  sometimes that's valid if the result of `grep` is tested, often by explicitly testing `$?`.  Of course there are better ways to do that but the pattern is common.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not with `grep -q` - it doesn't produce any output.  I think `service` command is writing to stderr.  So, you need to redirect it:

```
service service1 status 2>&1 | grep -q "good"
```

Unless this is done, `grep` won't see the output of `service` hence it won't be logically correct as well.